# Insert the id of a div var (by searching its exact class name) into an input value

Tags: javascript, input, get, element

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="stats" id="sdell_ac359636_ert_stats">
<var class="time" id="sdell_ac359636_time" style="color: red; font-size: 18px;">00:00</var> <var class="user" id="sdell_ac359636_select" style="display: none;">anything</var>
<div class="user_who_left"><span class="left_list_other_user">anything</span></div>
</div>
```

The class "user" is fixed, the id changes each page, but it always ends with "_select". Is not my website, so I cannot control that.

What I would like to do is to insert the id "sdell_ac359636_select" into the default value of the following js form:

```
var idDivText = this._getRandomID();
        var idDivBtn = this._getRandomID();
        layer.innerHTML += '<input type="text" value="!!!id goes here!!!" id="'+idDivText+'"/>';
        layer.innerHTML += '<input id="'+idDivBtn+'" type="button" value="START"/>';
```

Trying for a while with no "luck".

Comment: so you are trying to get data from another site? not with javascript i hope.

Comment: is part of a Chrome extension script.

Comment: I'm not familiar with chrome extension script but this looks like a regex problem to me. you can find the select with a regex like this `/sdell_(.*)_select/`

Comment: is just a regular javascript, nothing more. I need a more descriptive example, so that I can follow up. I am not a script expert, just trying to improve one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you get the site contents as a string. You can use regex to select the id you need and put it into your form:

```
var data = '<div class="stats" id="sdell_ac359636_ert_stats"><var class="time" id="sdell_ac359636_time" style="color: red; font-size: 18px;">00:00</var> <var class="user" id="sdell_ac359636_select" style="display: none;">anything</var><div class="user_who_left"><span class="left_list_other_user">anything</span></div></div>';

var re = new RegExp('class="user" id="sdell_(.*?)_select');
var ta = re.exec(data);
var foundId = ta[1];
var idDivText = this._getRandomID();
var idDivBtn = this._getRandomID();
layer.innerHTML += '<input type="text" value="' + foundId + '" id="'+idDivText+'"/>';
layer.innerHTML += '<input id="'+idDivBtn+'" type="button" value="START"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript:

```
var userEl = document.getElementsByClassName('user');

if( userEl.length > 0 ) {
  console.log( userEl[0].id );
}
```